# debian cron bug or missing something?

Tags: ubuntu, timezone, cron, debian

I'm configuring a server in N.Virginia to have the same cron schedule as our 'old' server with America/Chicago timezone.
I've edited /etc/timezone to have the value America/Chicago.
I have the environment variable TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central .
I've basically matched the old server, and both are on the NTP network.

The cron schedule is definitely stuck on UTC. It wouldn't be because of this 8yr old bug that was fixed in April 2010 ? The current server is running older stuff so probably not.

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=166533

new server info:
uname -a
Linux omittedhostname #7-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 13 19:55:22 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

current server info:
Linux omittedhostname 2.6.24-23-xen #1 SMP Mon Jan 26 03:09:12 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I solved it.

Doing zdump /etc/localtime between the 2 machines produced different output.

On the new server, I basically did:
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central /etc/localtime

If that wasn't it, I'll be surprised.